# Showing BigQuery sharded tables as a group on BigQuery Web UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I look at BigQuery tables auto created as part of the Google Analytics to BigQuery data export, tables that are created on a daily basis are grouped as below. 
[image]

I also have a set of manually created tables that have a common prefix.
e.g.
test_table_123
test_table_235
etc..

Currently these table are shown as: 
[image]

I would like these tables to be shown as `test_table_(2)` instead.


Can I know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are referring about [`_TABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables):**

It can be used in almost any format `<string><_TABLE_SUFFIX>` and can be used for querying multiple tables.

I couldn't find the documentation about the representation on the BigQuery Webui, but, the only format that is compressed as you want on the UI (`table_name_(<number_of_tables>)`) is **when you use a date**, in the format `table_name_yyyymmdd`, other table suffixes are not being compressed by the Webui.

**Ways to go:**

- Use a table name with the format `table_name_yyyymmdd` if it makes sense for your application

or

- Open a feature request on [issue-tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

**Examples of my tests:**

- one table with integer suffix and another with date suffix:
  [image]
- Date suffix compress the tables and create a filter on the UI:
  [image]
- Integer suffix don't compress or create filter:
  [image]